# Assigning positive weight for data set having both positive and negative numbers

Tags: statistics, average

I have a data set containing both positive and negative numbers. Say, for example the following $10$ values:

```
11,
45,
68,
-18,
29,
22,
-8,
-12,
54,
33
```

I have to assign proportionate weights to each of these values such that the highest value ($68$) gets maximum weight and the lowest one ($-18$) gets the least weight. However, the weights should be POSITIVE.

If it had been a list of only positive numbers, I would simply take the sum of all $10$ numbers, and divide each number by that sum to get proportionate positive weight for each.

However, this data set contains negative numbers also, so a few of the weights will go negative if the above method is followed.

**What would be the best way to "adjust" the weights so as to arrive only at positive weight values?** Is there any method to adjust each of the core data values themselves ($10$ in this case)?

There are multiple applications for this: allocating budgets to states which are running surplus while others running deficit, or making proportionate investments in projects which have positive and negative NPVs, etc.

I am open to use any mathematical function as suitable, like log, exponent, etc.

Comment: I have the same issue and I think I'm going to increase all by the min (maybe (min*2) so min isn't zero), but not sure the best-practices way